# Why my site doesn't work in php/localhost. css, img src etc

Tags: html, css

Css and code like "img src" doesn't work on localhost in php.
on html images and css work without problems, I have no idea why.
I would ask for help
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rozgrywki futbolowe</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ser/styl3.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="baner">
        <h2>Światowe rozgrywki piłkarskie</h2>
        <img src="C:/Users/kamka/OneDrive/Pulpit/ser/obraz1.jpg" alt="boisko">
    </div>
    <div class="mecze">
        <!-- skrypt1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="glowny">
        <h2>Reprezentacja Polski</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="lewy">
        <p>Podaj pozycję zawodników (1-bramkarze, 2-obrońcy, 3-pomocnicy, 4-napastnicy):</p>
        <form action="futbol.php" method="POST">
            <input type="number" name="" id="">
            <button type="submit">Sprawdź</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li>Skrypt2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="prawy">
        <img src="C:/Users/kamka/OneDrive/Pulpit/ser/zad1.png" alt="piłkarz">
        <p>Autor:2343274732</p>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: This is not a PHP question. You have a typo at the end of your script `</head>` should be `</html>`. `<img src="C:/` should be `file:///c:/` I believe and will only work on your machine.. possible, if security policy is loose enough to allow that.

Comment: Your URLs shouldn't include the `C:/Users/kamka/OneDrive/Pulpit/` prefix. It you want the resources to work both in the `file:///...` and `http://localhost/...` contexts. Use `<img src="ser/obraz1.jpg" alt="boisko">` (for example), similar to how you refer to the CSS stylesheet already. Also, since there is a form on your page, none of that stuff will work correctly in `file:////` context either way, so you'll have to start using your webserver (which likely means urls starting with `http://localhost/...`).